# Overview of objects in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just started to use Eclipse for my Java programmaing. I just wonder if there is some kind of list or similar of all created objects when you runt an application? Since there are icons for methods, variables and classes in the projects Package Explorer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you:

- set a breakpoint
- run the application in debug mode

when execution reaches the breakpoint, it will pause, and Eclipse lets you interactively search through all the objects currently in scope.